# how to delete a specific shape in a sheet using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with a lot of shapes.  I need to delete only the shapes which are located after row 15, and shapes which have Resize and Clear All written on it.
The shapes are a rectangle: rounded corners keeping text and having a macro assigned

[image: e.g]

How you can see in the image, I will have pictures (screenshots) and  it cant be deleted, the thing I am trying to delete is the blue "button".

Comment: `If oShape.Name = "Resize" Or  oShape.Name = "Clear All" Then`.

Comment: Are those shapes actually named "Resize" and "Clear All" though? A shape's name is not the same as its text.

Comment: What kind of shapes are they? ActiveX or Form controls? Rectangles keeping text and having a macro assigned?

Comment: @BigBen Did not work. the shapes are still in the sheet

Comment: See @FunThomas's answer.

Comment: @FaneDuru they are really shape from insert shapes and it has a macro assign to it.

Comment: @FaneDuru they are a rectangle: rounded corners keeping text and having a macro assigned

Comment: Then, try my answer code, please!

Comment: Didn't my answer code solve your problem? If your shapes are of a different type from the one you specified, I updated the answer with a version able to solve all types...

Comment: I am trying it now @FaneDuru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the next code, please (now it deletes only rounded corners rectangles according to your conditions):

```
Sub testDeleteInsertedShapes()
Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Shape, shR As ShapeRange, rng As Range
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Cells(15, Columns.count))

  Application.EnableEvents = False
  For Each sh In ws.Shapes
    If sh.Type = 1 Then 'rounded rectangles
        If Not Intersect(sh.TopLeftCell, rng) Is Nothing Then
            If sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.text = "Resize" Or _
                 sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.text = "Clear All" Then
                sh.Delete
            End If
        Else
            sh.Delete
        End If
    End If
  Next
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

And a code version deleting all shapes type (excepting pictures), I start working before you answered my question:

```
Sub deleteShapesAllTypes()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Shape, shR As ShapeRange, rng As Range
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Cells(15, Columns.count))
  Debug.Print rng.Address
  For Each sh In ws.Shapes
    If sh.Type = 8 Then
        If Not Intersect(sh.TopLeftCell, rng) Is Nothing Then
            If sh.OLEFormat.Object.text = "Resize" Or _
                   sh.OLEFormat.Object.text = "Clear All" Then
                sh.Delete
            End If
        Else
            sh.Delete
        End If
    ElseIf sh.Type = 12 Then
        If Not Intersect(sh.TopLeftCell, rng) Is Nothing Then
            If sh.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Caption = "Resize" Or _
                   sh.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Caption = "Clear All" Then
                sh.Delete
            End If
        Else
            sh.Delete
        End If
    Else
        If sh.Type <> 13 Then
            If Not Intersect(sh.TopLeftCell, rng) Is Nothing Then
                If sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.text = "Resize" Or _
                     sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.text = "Clear All" Then
                    sh.Delete
                End If
            Else
                sh.Delete
            End If
        End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The first one deleted everything. I will edit my post and show what I mean

Comment: @Fah: It deletes everything below row 5. Now, I can see that it should be below 15. I will adapt the code. Updated it...

Comment: @Fah: Adapted the code to delete only round rectangles shapes...

Comment: however, it is not supposed to delete everything. I need it to delete only the "blue Buttons". The screenshots need to stay.

Comment: @Fah: if the "blue Buttons" are rounded corners rectangles, the updated version deletes only such shapes. But, **do not forget to refresh the page**! Otherwise, you can use the old code... You did not say anything in your initial question about other shapes type to be somehow protected for deletion... :)

Comment: It worked,  But it crashed the excel, I mean it closed the excel  and open the file again with no change

Comment: @Fah:  Did you use the code like it is (the first one)? I tested it  many times and it works as you recently explained your need.... If you modified something, event not looking significant, can you update your question with the code you used, please?

Comment: I edited the post, maybe now is more clear. 
With your code (both of them) it worked to deleted only the "blue buttons" but when the code call the merge alerts, for some reason the blue buttons on this sheet changes the range and is placed in the wrong place.

Comment: Maybe it is happen because the code is calling automatically a compare text code.`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B17")) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B17")) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = True
Call ChgTxtColorRules
'Call ChgTxtColor
End If`

End Sub`

Comment: @Fah:  I do not have time to analize your event, but I will adapt the code to avoid this event... Updated the code!

Comment: @Fah: Glad to here that it finally worked... It is good to also be more focused on the way you ask a question... :)

Comment: Well, I asked the part I needed :(. However, I will pay more attention in my questions. The deleting part is working perfectly, but for some reason it still change the position of the "blue buttons" on the new sheet. (probably I will only run another code to put it back on place).

Comment: What `rename`, which is called by the event, does?

Comment: No problem, I changed the code a bit and it is working fine. (it is not calling the event anymore).Thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score 2):

First, your If-statement is wrong, see BigBen's comment:

```
If oShape.Name = "Resize" Or oShape.Name = "Clear All" Then
```

However, this will check the name of the shapes, not their text. To get the text of the shape, you can use `oShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text`. However, you can face two small issues with that:

(1) There are shapes without text, e.g. Pictures. This can be checked with `oShape.TextFrame2.HasText`

(2) It may be the case that the text has a newline at the end or that it has contains leading or trailing spaces, so I would suggest you write the content into a variable and use the `Instr`-function:

```
if oShape.TextFrame2.HasText Then
    dim shapeText as string
    shapeText = oShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
    if InStr(shapeText, "Resize") > 0 or InStr(shapeText, "Clear All") > 0 then
       oShape.Delete
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Did not work. probably I am doing something wrong. it will have pictures in the sheet as well, but only this rectangle: rounded corners  need to be deleted

Comment: Have you debugged your code to see where it is failing?

Comment: Sorry, the `Then` was missing - cut and paste error. You have that in your original loop? Can you check if `oShape` is set to something and if yes, if `oShape.TextFrame2` is set?

Comment: yes, I am getting error error: Run-Time error 91: Object variable or block variable not set  in this line `shapeText = oShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.text`

Comment: no it is not set. the only thing I have is Dim oShape As Shape

Comment: I've omitted the for loop and the `InterSect`-check from your code as they look okay. Of course you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub shapeKiller()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, nm As String, rw As Long
    Dim sh As Shape
    N = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count

    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes(i)
        nm = sh.Name
        rw = sh.TopLeftCell.Row
        If nm = "Resize" Or nm = "Clear All" Or rw > 15 Then
            sh.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```